# Swiftmailer: get body ContentType after a part has been added

Tags: php, swiftmailer

If a message has a body and type set with `$message->setBody($body, $type)`, I can get the body back with `$message->getBody()` and the type with `$message->getContentType()`.

But if a part is then added with `$message->addPart($partBody, $partType)`, things change. `$message->getBody()` still gives me the original body, but `$message->getContentType()` gives me `multipart/alternative`. I realize that the type of the message has changed to this, and I understand why, but I need a way to get back the type of the original body. At this point `$message->getChildren()` returns an array of length 1, and only has the part which was added later. I can get the body and type of that part just fine.

I know the original body type still exists somewhere it the object, because if I send the message that body part has its own correct `Content-Type` header. But is it exposed? How can I get it?

Edit: I dug into the code and as far as I can tell it's not possible to retrieve. I've now [posted on their issue tracker](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/736).

Comment: I am looking for exactly the same thing and it makes me nuts. I am currently thinking about getting the children and their content type and then assume that the body content type is the other one.

Comment: I considered that too, but yuck.